# Turning a local variable into a private variable breaks my C# code

Tags: c#

In my console application I have a local variable that's working fine

the moment I make it a private variable to the class, I can't compile, because it says - an object reference is required for the non static member or property

Any ideas what could be the reason, this is the first time I've seen this.

Comment: I think that showing us some code would *probably* help.

Comment: Actually, we don't need it in this case, but it's still a good idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Declare your private variable as static. You're trying to access a non-static variable from a static function. Note that Main() is static.

Comment: This NEVER happened to me before (just kidding).

Answer (score 5):

Your Main method is a static method, which means that it is not associated with a specific instance of your Program class.  When you added a private field, it was an instance variable, which means that there is a copy of it associated with each instance of the class.

Since your Main method is static, it cannot use the instance member without an instance.

The simplest solution is to make the field a static field (add the `static` keyword to the declaration).